# How to keep the newline char in json parse and show it in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using Json to pass value from controller to jquery. In my JS my array is

```
ReqDetails  "[\"\",\"\",\"801 , Ann , 1.1.1.1\\n902 , Max , 1.1.1.1\\n983 , Olli , 1.1.1.1\\n\"]"
var str = JSON.parse(ReqDetails);

will result in str = [,,801 , Ann , 1.1.1.1902 , Max , 1.1.1.1983, Olli , 1.2]
```

my tooltip is showing the str, so it shows the whole array in one line. Also it removed the new line char.

```
801 , Ann , 1.1.1.1902 , Max , 1.1.1.1983 , Olli , 1.2
```

but i would like to show tooltip with new line

```
801 , Ann , 1.1.1.1
902 , Max , 1.1.1.1
983 , Olli , 1.2
```

Can anyone tell how to do this?

Comment: You're sure the issue isn't just that newlines don't mean anything in HTML, you'd need a `<br>`

Comment: How do you show it? Your newlines are escaped by an extra \. So replacing \\n with \n, I'm able to show it in alert box: http://plnkr.co/edit/sZbpGqVUI2zCMoPGKRB7?p=preview.